# Can I ask for screenshot of some great personalized IDE for python?

Tags: python, open-source, development-environment

How to setup a Linux/Unix machine for python development? Which Linux/Unix version should I use? What IDE should be used? What development plugins should I have? What code style should would be THE BEST? All above, a great development machine for open source (python developers) development?

**Can i ask for screenshot of some great personalized IDE for Python?** All platform users are invited. Please, do include the source/plugin/article how you made it.

Thanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "BEST"?  Cheapest?  Fastest?  Largest?  Most Complex?  Simplest?

Comment: @S.Lott choice is yours I need just best :)

Comment: @Ramiz Uddin: I choose most complex.  Use notepad on windows and transfer the files to Linux with FTP.

Comment: @S.Lott was expecting something similar from you :)

Comment: lovely gentoo emacs python environment http://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/ThierryVolpiatto

Comment: @Ramiz Uddin: It's your question.  You must choose what you mean when you say "best".  If you don't provide a definition for "best", your question cannot be answered except by us guessing what you meant.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Which Linux/Unix version should I use?   Doesn't matter.  They all work.  Pick one that you're going to be successful with.

What IDE should be used? Duplicate:  [What IDE to use for Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/81584/what-ide-to-use-for-python)

What development plugins should I have?  No clue from the vague question.

What code style should would be THE BEST?   "BEST" doesn't mean anything.  Nor does "style".  Everyone follows [PEP-8](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/), if that's helpful.

All above, a great development machine for open source (python developers) development?  Doesn't matter.  They all work.

Comment: Also WRT style, read http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html

Answer (score 0):

- Install any of the Linux distributions on your computer. If you have a preference, great. If not, try Ubuntu, Fedora, Debian. Any of them is pretty user and developer friendly too.
- IDE, well I don't use one. But you may try NetBeans with Python support or Eclipse (with PyDev).
- Code style- well, try and learn to be pythonic. It should come with practice and asking questions

I think that should get you started!

Comment: @Amit do you use emacs/vim for development?

Comment: I primarily used Vim, till recently. I am currently on Emacs and am loving it. There again, its a question of preference. Start with one, and stick to one you are comfortable with.

Answer (score 0):

I use ubuntu 10.4 with [geany](http://geany.org/) and [standard python code style](http://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). Basically that's all I need. I can install python packages both from ubuntu repos and using easy install (you can actually use it on all supported platforms). You don't need much for Python. It's small and flexible :-)

Answer (score 0):

Any of the new Linux distros should be fine, though Ubuntu is very user friendly when you are starting. You will also be happier starting with a simple editor like gedit / geany. But do make an attempt to learn emacs / vim. You will get the hang of one of those and it can really be life changing (I use emacs). As a great development machine, I recommend thinkpads for the excellent full size keyboards and linux friendly hardware. [This image](http://durdn.com/blog/wp-content/uploads/2008/07/picture-2.png) is a fairly representative screenshot of python development on emacs.